# How to use regex in custom paths for Cucumber

Tags: regex, mapping, cucumber

I have a path in paths.rb:

```
when /the page for CA/
   '/CA-area-code'
```

But, I would like to regex a portion of the path so that it pulls the value from the regex in the feature step. Like so:

```
when /the Phone SEO page for (.*)/
   '/#{foo}-area-code'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
when /the Phone SEO page for (.*)/
   '/#{$1}-area-code'
```

should do it.